# How to change the next N elements on hover in document

Tags: css

I think I am almost there but struggling with selecting elements that fall outside the :hover div

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="cotainer">
<div class=box"><i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i><i>4</i></div>
<div class=box"><i>5</i><i>6</i><i>7</i><i>8</i></div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I am trying to use but failing:

```
.box:hover i:nth-child(-n+6){color:red;}
```

The problem is that only elements 1 to 4 change to red.

What is the solution to change elements 1 to 6? Thank you :)

Comment: elements 1-4 and 5-6 doesn't' belong to the same element hovered

Answer (score 0):

You can consider siblings selector (`+`) and split the selection for the first and second part:

```css
.box:hover i,
.box:hover + .box i:nth-child(-n+2){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cotainer">
  <div class="box"><i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i><i>4</i></div>
  <div class="box"><i>5</i><i>6</i><i>7</i><i>8</i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Temani, I added nth-child and works perfectly :)
    .box:hover i,
    .box:hover + .box i:nth-child(-n+2){
     color: red;
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is the way:

```css
.container:hover > .box:nth-child(1){
  color: red;
}

.container:hover > .box:nth-child(2) > i:nth-child(-n+2){
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"><i>1</i><i>2</i><i>3</i><i>4</i></div>
  <div class="box"><i>5</i><i>6</i><i>7</i><i>8</i></div>
</div>
```